# If $0<x<1$ and $x$ is rational, does $2^x$ have to be irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, rationality-testing

If $0<x<1$ and $x$ is rational, does $2^x$ have to be irrational? Why? Also, if $2^x$ is rational, and $0<x<1$ and $x$ is rational, does $x$ have to be irrational? (i.e. contrapositive of the first statement)

I believe a better (and easier) way would be to prove the latter statement and then the former one would be proven as well (due to contra-positivity), however I was unable to prove that anyway.

Comment: Do you know the proof that $\sqrt 2=2^{1/2}$ is not rational? If so you could try adapting the proof for arbitrary rational number in $(0,1)$

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that if $2^{a/b}=\frac mn$ then $2^a\times n^b=m^b$

Comment: The contrapositive of the statement you wrote is actually: "if $2^x$ is rational, then it is not true that both $0<x<1$ and $x$ is rational hold". In more natural language, "if $2^x$ is rational, then $x$ is irrational or $x\not\in(0,1)$".

Comment: I don't know why you downvote this user, it's a new user so they need guidance. The question is interesting

Comment: You should look [in here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to make your answers look nice, and make sure to include efforts in your answers in the future, especially if it's an elementary question, people see questions of this kind in a better light.

Comment: My second thought was that there is some general theorem that can be used as overkill to easily prove this, in particular, I was thinking of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem . But on second thoughts I don't see how this theorem can easily be used to prove that $2^{p/q}$ is irrational for integer $p,q$ with $q>p.$

Comment: If $x=p/q,$ the. $y=2^x$ is a root of $y^q-2^p,$ and the rational root theorem and unique factorization says the only rational roots can be $\pm 2^i$ for $i=0,1,\dots,p.$

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $a,b,p,q\in\Bbb N$ and $\gcd(p,q)=1$. If $2^{p/q}=\frac ab$ then $2^pb^q=a^q$.

Let's call, for any natural $n$, $v(n)$ the greatest natural $r$ such that $2^r$ divides $n$.

So $v(2^pb^q)=v(a^q)$, and $p+qv(b)=qv(a)$. Then $p$ is a multiple of $q$. Since $p$ and $q$ are coprime, $q=1$.

Answer (score 2):

$2^\frac{p}{q}$ is the solution of the equation $x^q-2^p=0$.

As per [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), the only way for a *rational* number $x=\frac{m}{n}$ (in its reduced form) to be a root of that equation is when $n\mid 1$ (and $m\mid 2^p$), which implies that $x$ itself is an integer (dividing $2^p$).

(Note: in Algebra we say that $\mathbb Z$ is the [ring of integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_integers) over $\mathbb Q$, as $\mathbb Z$ is precisely the set of rational zeros of *monic* polynomials, i.e., polynomials with leading coefficient $1$. The proof is the same as above, using the Rational Root Theorem.)

Thus, no such solution can be strictly between $1=2^0$ and $2=2^1$, which would be the case for $0<\frac{p}{q}<1$.

Comment: Um... after posting this answer I've seen that @ThomasAndrews had a comment with the same idea. I promise I did not peek into those comments before posting!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\frac ab\in \mathbb Q$, where $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $0<a<b$

Prove by contradictions, assume $2^x\in \mathbb Q$, then $$2^x=2^{\frac a b}=\frac p q,~~~\gcd(p,q)=1\Longrightarrow 2^aq^b=p^b\Longrightarrow p\in \text{even}$$

Since $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $p$ is even, then $q$ must be odd.

Let $p=2^kp_o$, where $\color{red}{k\ge1}$ and $p_o$ is odd. We get

$$2^aq^b=2^{bk}p_o^b$$

Since both $q^b$ and $p_o^b$ are odd, it implies
$$2^a=2^{bk}\Longrightarrow a=bk$$

since we know $0<a<b$, hence

$$bk<b\Longrightarrow k<1$$

which contradicts with the fact $\color{red}{k\ge1}$

Comment: MathFail, congratulation for you proof (+1).

Comment: Thank you! @Angelo